# SQL transpose based on values in col 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query that gives me a 2 column result like this:

```
A | B
-----
2 | 1
3 | 2
3 | 3
3 | 4
3 | 5
4 | 6
4 | 7
4 | 8
4 | 9
```

I would like to split this up into multiple columns like this. Each for each row in `A` with a particular value convert that into columns. The maximum number of rows a particular value say *x* can occur in column `A` is 4 (if that helps).

```
A | B1   | B2   | B3  |  B4 
----------------------------
2 | 1    | NULL | NULL | NULL
3 | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5
4 | 6    | 7    | 8    | 9
```

I have been stuck trying to do this using pivot for hours. I am now thinking about querying this in python (the client using this) and doing the transformation there (which is easy). But can this be done in SQL? I am using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select a,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then b end) as b_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then b end) as b_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then b end) as b_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then b end) as b_4
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by a;
```

Comment: This works for me. Just curious, was this possible without knowing that the maximum number of rows a particular value can occur in column A is 4?

Comment: @PyMan . . . If you don't know the maximum number, then you would need to use dynamic SQL (much messier).  Or just put the values into a single column using `string_agg()` -- after you upgrade your version of SQL Server to a supported version.